# How can a Mac OS X user protect themselves from shell-shock AND remain connected to the internet right now

Tags: macos, shellshock, bash

Seems to me that there is a need to remain online, esp. for business users and that even when this is corrected, there will be a need to go back online to get the Apple patch. e.g. Is removing bash a viable workaround to remain secure for the moment.

Comment: Duplicate question:  http://security.stackexchange.com/a/68204/52676  You'll have to be online at some point to patch your system.  Unless you already have the bash source code and compile a patch yourself.

Comment: No this question is intended to ask about any possible workarounds that could mitigate the risks, not necessarily how to patch bash. I'll update my question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Business users can mitigate their risk using their perimeter IPS protection (or palo alto nextgen firewalls) for CVE-2014-6271 but need to wait for released protection on the related CVE-2014-7219 over the next 24 hours.

Source (in my case palo alto):  https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here ia a basic set of pretty simple rules for an end user:

[Are Macs vulnerable to the Bash shellshock bug?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147145/22003).

The purpose is to remove any remote access to a shell, may it be directly `/bin/bash` or any other shell which may let switch to `/bin/bash` and use it to escalate priviledge.

Answer (score 0):

The patch for the bug is available here:

[Apple bash bug patch](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1769)

It is possible to Airdrop connect to another device, transfer the patch DMG from that device and then install the patch - all without connecting the target machine to the internet.